# Java web service: code running after start

Tags: java, web-services

As far as I know, constructor of web service is called only when client connects, but not when  the service is started. Is there any way to run some part of code at the time web service starts?

Answer (score 0):

You havent mentioned which framework you are using. I guess its jersey. If so, this post on stackoverflow might be what you are looking for

[How does one intercept a request during the Jersey lifecycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358213/how-does-one-intercept-a-request-during-the-jersey-lifecycle)