# How to use Jersey interceptors to get request body

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am using `REST-Jersey` in my project. All the POST data is send in `JSON` format and unmarshalled at server-side into respective beans. Something like this:

Sending request to server:

```
    $('a#sayHelloPost').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var mangaData = {
            title:'Bleach',
            author:'Kubo Tite'
        }
        var formData=JSON.stringify(mangaData);
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
                url:'rest/cred/sayposthello',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType:'application/json'
        })
});
```

Payload:

```
{"title":"Bleach","author":"Kubo Tite"}
```

Server-end:

```
@POST
@Path("/sayposthello")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response sayPostHello(MangaBean mb){
    System.out.println(mb);
    return Response.status(200).build();
}
```

MangaBean:

```
public class MangaBean {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MangaBean [title=" + title + ", author=" + author + "]";
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

Output on console:

```
MangaBean [title=Bleach, author=Kubo Tite]
```

I got the REST-interceptor implementation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358213/how-does-one-intercept-a-request-during-the-jersey-lifecycle).

```
public class JerseyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest req) {
        return req;
    }

}
```

I want to access the payload(request body) in the interceptor. As the data is in JSON format, its not accessible as request parameters. **Is there a way I can get the request body in the interceptor method?** Please advice.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is one way you can implement, very similar to how Jersey implements its logging filters. You can read the entity and stick it back to the request, so you accidentally do not consume it in your filter.

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException;
import com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class JerseyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream in = request.getEntityInputStream();
        final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            if (in.available() > 0) {
                ReaderWriter.writeTo(in, out);

                byte[] requestEntity = out.toByteArray();
                printEntity(b, requestEntity);

                request.setEntityInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(requestEntity));
            }
            return request;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new ContainerException(ex);
        }

    }

    private void printEntity(StringBuilder b, byte[] entity) throws IOException {
        if (entity.length == 0)
            return;
        b.append(new String(entity)).append("\n");
        System.out.println("#### Intercepted Entity ####");
        System.out.println(b.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Original InputStream was not closed in the code. I would do this in try-with-resources way, and assign newly constructed input stream outside of the try-with-resources block. Also, ContainerRequestFilter interface has been modified since then and filter() signature is different now.

Comment: request.setEntityInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(requestEntity));
Why we need to set Input stream again to ContainerRequest object?

Comment: @DeepakGangore because once the original InputStream is read, it consumes the request payload, so the server would not be able to receive the original stream, interfering on the request process

Answer (score 6):

You can only read the content once, because it's an input stream.  If you pick it up in the interceptor then you won't be able to provide it in the main parsing.

What you need to do is to create a filter which reads the data and makes it available to anyone else who needs it.  Basic steps are:

- in your filter create a new subclass of HttpServletRequestWrapper which reads the input in to a buffer and overrides getInputStream() to provide a new input stream to that buffer
- pass your new subclass down the chain

Answer (score 4):

You can get the POST Body from the Requests Input Stream.
Try something like this:

```java
    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest req) {
        try{
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();       
            IOUtils.copy(req.getEntityInputStream(), writer, "UTF-8");
        
            //This is your POST Body as String      
            String body = writer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        return req;
    }
```

Comment: I did try reading from the InputStream before but got a `java.io.EOFException:No content to map to Object due to end of input`. Same happened with your example. Any suggestions?

Comment: You must decide where you want to read the object. Once the object (mb) is read from the Filter it wont be availble for Jackson since the InputStream is already used.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `in.available()` method to check the total bytes of Inputstream. Some clients does not set this value. And in this case it will be foul eventhough the message body input stream exists.

```
 InputStream in = request.getEntityInputStream();
        final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            if (in.available() > 0)
```

Use below code

```
String json = IOUtils.toString(requestContext.getEntityStream(), Charsets.UTF_8);
            messageBody = json;
            InputStream in = IOUtils.toInputStream(json);
            requestContext.setEntityStream(in);
```