# Jersey InputStream is modified in filter. Unable to figure out how to access modified inputStream in Jersey Resource

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

As discussed in [How to use Jersey interceptors to get request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560276/how-to-use-jersey-interceptors-to-get-request-body), I am modifying the EntityInputStream in a ContainerRequestFilter.

```
public filter(ContainerRequest request){
     ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     InputStream in = request.getEntityInputStream(); 
     try{
           Readerwriter.writeTo(in, out);
           byte[] requestEntity = out.toByteArray();

           // DO SOMETHING WITH BYTES HERE

           request.setEntityInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(requestEntity));

      }/// error handling code here  
}
```

However, later on I can't figure out how to access the modified InputStream.  I can get the ServletContext in the resource, but I can't figure out how to get ahold of the object I actually modified in the filter, the ContainerRequest.

Can I do something like this?  Jersey can't start up out when I try this:

```
@Post
@Path("/test")
public Response test(@Context ContainerRequest cr){
     // blah blah
     return....
}
```

Jersey error:

Missing dependecy for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response example.TestController.test(com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest), annotated with POST of resource, class example.TestController, is not recognized as a valid resource method.

I am stuck on an old version of jersey, 1.8, so I'm not sure if that's part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is accept an `InputStream` as the entity body in your resource method. If you want the `ByteArrayInputStream` just cast it.

```
@POST
public Response post(InputStream in) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bin = (ByteArrayInputStream)in;
}
```

If you don't already know, how Jersey converts the request stream (for the request body) into Java types (for instance JSON to POJO) is through [`MessageBodyReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html)s. You can read more about them at [JAX-RS Entity Providers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html).

Jersey already comes with some standard readers for easily convertible types, for instance String. Most content-types can be converted to String. Likewise, it has a reader to handle `InputStream`. This is probably the easiest conversion, as the request is already coming in as an `InputStream`, so really all the reader would need to do is return the original stream, and that's what would get passed to our method.

If we look at the implementation [`InputStreamProvider`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/blob/master/jersey-core/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/core/impl/provider/entity/InputStreamProvider.java), we can see that that's what actually happens. [The original stream is simply returned](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/blob/master/jersey-core/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/core/impl/provider/entity/InputStreamProvider.java#L74). And since the filter happens before the readers, the reader simply returns the stream that we set.

Here is a complete example using [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#test-framework)

```
public class StreamFilterTest extends JerseyTest {

    public static class InputStreamFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

        @Override
        public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                InputStream in = request.getEntityInputStream();
                ReaderWriter.writeTo(in, out);

                byte[] requestBytes = out.toByteArray();
                byte[] worldBytes = " World".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                byte[] newBytes = new byte[requestBytes.length + worldBytes.length];
                System.arraycopy(requestBytes, 0, newBytes, 0, requestBytes.length);
                System.arraycopy(worldBytes, 0, newBytes, requestBytes.length, worldBytes.length);

                request.setEntityInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(newBytes));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(InputStreamFilter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }

            return request;
        }
    }

    @Path("stream")
    public static class StreamResource {

        @POST
        public String post(InputStream in) throws Exception {
            ByteArrayInputStream bin = (ByteArrayInputStream) in;
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            ReaderWriter.writeTo(new InputStreamReader(bin), writer);
            return writer.toString();
        }
    }

    public static class AppConfig extends DefaultResourceConfig {
        public AppConfig() {
            super(StreamResource.class);
            getContainerRequestFilters().add(new InputStreamFilter());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public WebAppDescriptor configure() {
        return new WebAppDescriptor.Builder()
                .initParam(WebComponent.RESOURCE_CONFIG_CLASS,
                        AppConfig.class.getName())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void should_return_hello_world() {
        String response = resource().path("stream").post(String.class, "Hello");
        assertEquals("Hello World", response);
    }
}
```

Here's the test dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```