# logger calls Jersey Project

Tags: java, jersey, tomcat8

I created one project WS REST with technologies Jersey-1.19, Jackson-1.9.2, log4j-1.2, Java and Servlet. And for run the project I use tomcat-8.

I need configure file log4j.properties for show me all REQUEST over all methods available in WS REST. It's possible?

Basicly, what i need do for logger all REQUEST?

my log4j.properties is:

```
#### Use two appenders, one to log to console, another to log to a file
logFolder = D:/logs
log4j.rootCategory=debug

#### First appender writes to console
log4j.appender.myConsole=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.myConsole.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.myConsole.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.myConsole.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{DATE} %-5p: [%C{1}.%M(%L)] %m%n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom logging filter if you want to customize the logging messages for request and response.

```
public class CustomLoggingFilter extends LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomLoggingFilter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("\nMethod : ").append(request.getMethod().toUpperCase())
                                .append("  Path : ").append(request.getRequestUri().getPath())
                                .append("\nHeaders : ").append(request.getRequestHeaders());

        logger.log(Level.INFO, "\nHTTP REQUEST" + sb.toString());

        return request;
    }

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("\nHeaders : ").append(response.getHttpHeaders());
        sb.append("\nStatus : ").append(response.getStatus());

        try {
            sb.append("\nEntity : ").append(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(response.getEntity()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "\nEntity : ERROR in converting entity to JSON for logging. " + e.getMessage());
        }

        logger.log(Level.INFO, "\nHTTP RESPONSE" + sb.toString());

        return response;
    }
}
```

In the web.xml you should use "[packagename].CustomLoggingFilter" instead of "com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter"

Comment: if you want see body from request the best example is http://stackoverflow.com/a/14579296/3703397

Answer (score 0):

My answer is here http://wpcertification.blogspot.pt/2012/06/enabling-request-and-response-logging.html .

Basicly, i need add in web.xml the follows parameters in definition of Jersey REST Servlet :

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: if you want see body from request the best example is http://stackoverflow.com/a/14579296/3703397