# How to get the data from ContainerRequestContext to build a DTO object

Tags: spring-boot, filter, jersey

I'm new in spring and jersey. I'm trying to build a Filter to check if the request have the correct parameters. This is the the part of the json that I want to check:

```
"request":{
        "application":"1 Android Mobile",
        "version":1
    }
```

The elements of the data is part of my VersionDTO:

```
public class VersionDTO {
    int version;
    String application;

    public String getApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    public void setApplication(String application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

}
```

This is the code of my filter:

```
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws FilterException {

        if (isSecureURL(requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath())){}{
            try {

                versionFilterService.setVersionDTO(//here is where I want to pass the VersionDTO object with the data of the requestContext);
            } catch (ServiceException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isSecureURL(String url) {
        return !UnSecureUrlEnum.isUnSecureUrl(url);
    }
}
```

That I want to do is get from the ContainerRequestContext the data and build a VersionDTO to can pass the object to my service. Is this possible??

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to get entities in filter, however you get request inputstream but you need to take care few things as only one time you can stream it. 
Check this out, it might help you..  [How to use Jersey interceptors to get request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560276/how-to-use-jersey-interceptors-to-get-request-body)

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's possible. With Jersey you can buffer the stream before reading it, allowing for the stream to be read again. You will need to cast to the Jersey `ContainerRequest` where you can `bufferEntity()` then simply `readEntity` to get the deserialized object.

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws FilterException {

    ContainerRequest cr = (ContanerRequest) requestContext;
    cr.bufferEntity();
    VersionDTO dto = cr.readEntity(VersionDTO.class);
}
```