# How to intercept and read request body in jersey REST service?

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a project where I have to intercept and read request body in a Jersey Rest Service. On the basis of body content I need to abort or proceed the request.

My project is not using Spring, and I am using **web.xml** for configuration. I have tried ***javax.servlet.Filter*** and ***javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter*** where I am able to intercept but not able to read request body. Also there is an example with ***com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter*** [[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560276/how-to-use-jersey-interceptors-to-get-request-body)] but I am not able to register filter itself.

**ServletContainer (web.xml)**

```xml
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>employeeservice</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myapp.endpoints.EmployeeService</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>employeeservice</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Endpoint**

```java
@Path("/service")
@Singleton
public class EmployeeService{


    @GET
    @Path("/get/employee/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getEmployeeDetails(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        // get employee details 
    }
}
```

**Request :**

GET http://localhost:8080/get/employee/123

```
body : { 
   "EmployeeType" : "Manager"
}
```

If "EmployeeType" is not "Manager" , it should abort the request.

Help me where I am missing? Please let me know If any other details required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the request from GET to POST in order to send body. GET calls only have parameters and the easiest thing you could do is:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/get/employee/123?typle="manager"
```

or to change POST:

```
> method = RequestMethod.POST
> 
> @Path("/connections") @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
> @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }) public interface
> EmployeeService{ 
> @POST     
> Response getEmployeeDetails(String body);
```

And implementation read:

> JSONObject json = new JSONObject(body);